# How to sort an SQL table/view by month and year?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

I have SQL table/view which has a column called "Month".The way data is displayed in this column "MonthName" + "Year".[image: "SQL TABLE"].I want to know if there is way to sort this by year and month ? I tried the "Order by Month" but that only sorts it alphabetically.

Comment: Order by the second column, which appears to be the number of months since November 2015 (if I'm interpreting this correctly)? Then possibly redesign the table so you have datetime fields. Edit: Actually doesn't appear that way after I looked a second time. Just go with a redesign instead.

Comment: If you don't have full date or any other options to get the year sequence, than you would have to substring the year from Month-Year field, as it is a string, as I understood. Then you can sort by this substring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `CONVERT` function on your `[Month]` column (Month + Year). That will convert each value to a `DATE` object corresponding to the first day of the month/year. Then do a sort on that:

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
 MyTable
ORDER BY
 CONVERT(DATE,[Month])
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Great to hear. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert colum ("Monnth" "Year") to DATE TYPE and order by DATE colum

```
SELECT
     TO_DATE('August 2017'
            ,'Month YYYY')
 FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: This would work on Oracle but OP tagged `sql-server`

Answer (score 0):

I would use a date field and sort by that.  You can use:

```
concate(DATENAME(month,MyDateField), " ", YEAR(MyDateField))
```

In a view, query, or a persisted computed column depending on what works best for you.